# Typo3 Upgrade 10.4 News Template/Layout not loading

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-10.x, tx-news

I have updated my Typo3 Website from v. 9.5 to 10.4.32. Everything is working fine so far.

The Layout of the News Pluging is not working anymore.

This is these are the extension config files:

typo3conf/ext/news/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt

```
# Important: This file is deprecated and will removed with EXT:news 10.x
@import 'EXT:news/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript'
```

typo3conf/ext/news/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript

```
plugin.tx_news {
    mvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1

    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/
            1 = {$plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPath}
        }

        partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Partials/
            1 = {$plugin.tx_news.view.partialRootPath}
        }

        layoutRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Layouts/
            1 = {$plugin.tx_news.view.layoutRootPath}
        }

        widget.GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }}
```

The News Extension is not using this templates. I think that typoscript has no effect.

What can be the problem? I am not a Typo3 guru so I am very glad if you can help.

Comment: And one of these two files is really included? Have you checked this via TS Object-Browser (BE-Module "Template")

Comment: Did you update news at the same time, and if yes, from which to which version?